# Postgresql equivalent of flashback

Tags: postgresql, flashback

I'm Oracle Dba and want to learn Postgresql. Does it have equivalent of flashback in Postgresql?

Comment: your best shot is [Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. Here's a good answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/362/30035

And ATM the best practice as Laurenz suggests here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B36614938%40ntex2010i.host.magwien.gv.at

the lagging slave can show you the value some time ago (look `recovery_min_apply_delay`, or `pg_xlog_replay_pause()` fro pre 9.4 releases) - of course it's not a FRA, but can give you some place to move